# Can I move the whole harddisk content of my PC to the cloud?

Tags: cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Computer renting (moving my desktop to the cloud)](https://superuser.com/questions/49897/remote-computer-renting-moving-my-desktop-to-the-cloud)

I'd like to move everything - data+software - from my notebook/XP to the cloud and run everything there from an Ipad. Is there an easy way to do this?

I ve seen there are high end solutions like citrix xendesktop, but it seems its more targeted to large companies (= expensive and IT-department necessary).

The thought behind it is, like this everything is always safe, and accessible from anywhere with everything (every computer with internet access).

Comment: Related [Remote Computer renting (moving my desktop to the cloud)](http://superuser.com/questions/49897/remote-computer-renting-moving-my-desktop-to-the-cloud)

Answer (score 0):

While you can move most of your data to the cloud, moving your applications to the cloud is not so easy.

Firstly you will need to fine Web apps that do what your applications are doing right now. This is quite possible for email, Word processing & basic Photo manipulation. But anything beyond that is going to be quite limited, and very different from a full desktop experience.

Secondly, The IPad is more of a consuming device, rather than a creating device. Even with the Keyboard, you will soon start hitting the limits when you try creating stuff, and writing ect.

The best way would be to backup your data with a service like dropbox.com and keep a full computer nearby to do your data creation and using your IPad for consumption.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to get a server which lets you connect via [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) or switch to web applications like google's office solutions.

AFAIK there's not one single Über-web-application for every task you might want to cover with it. You should keep in mind, that you have to use different apps hosted on different sites, if you want to go down the web-only road.

Another approach would be sharing your data via some service (or, again, your own server) that you can access from your iPad. That way you can work with a copy and sync changes back to your online storage (the "cloud").

But i wouldn't go with either approach if i were you. You'll never know where your data is stored, who as access to it and how safe they really are. What if the datacenter, where your files are stored and processed, burns down and the company you selected for hosting doesn't have off site backups (such [things](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2009/01/magnolia-suffer/) [really](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13846_3-10026977-62.html) [happen](http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/archives/2009/10/10/t-mobile-microsoft-lost-all-the-sidekick-backups/)...). IF you choose to store your data somewhere, be sure to check if you can encrypt it or encrypt it yourself.

And think of another simple scenario: What happens if you don't have web access for a few days (phone line was cut, no mobile coverage for some reason, etc). Your data is somewhere safe, but you can't work with it either.

IMHO you should keep your data where it is, maybe use the web or a server at home/offsite for backing it up and syncing with your iPad. But do not rely on 3rd parties to keep your data safe!